# easy struts example cannot find jsp

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have a struts example, I am able to access index.jsp, but success.jsp cannot be accessed and resulted in HTTP 404 error. Could someone help me, Thanks in advance.
Here is my project structure.
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o381.png)

**web.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <filter>
          <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
          <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
          <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
          <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="hello" class="com.action.IndexAction">
            <result name="success">/views/success.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**success.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="utf8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My JSP 'success.jsp' starting page</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2><s:property value="message"/></h2><br>
  </body>
</html>
```

**IndexAction.java**

```
package com.action;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class IndexAction extends ActionSupport {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String MESSAGE = "struct is running";
    private String message = "";

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        setMessage(MESSAGE);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the action for.

Answer (score 1):

According to your application structure, you might have put **success.jsp** is under **/WEB-INF/views**. so

`<result name="success">/views/success.jsp</result>` would be

`<result name="success">/WEB-INF/views/success.jsp</result>`

Modified:

**Struts.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="hello" class="com.action.IndexAction">
            <result name="success">/WEB-INF/views/success.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: omg, you are right, I got stuck with this problem for hours. Thank you so much, I am always confused with namespace. Thank u. :)

Comment: your problem solved?  if you accept the answer, it means your problem has been solved with the answer.

Comment: @Xin This isn't an issue with namespaces, it's an issue with not providing the path to a file.

Comment: yes.. it is the issue with `<result name="success">/WEB-INF/views/success.jsp</result>`